# PyQGIS 'exporter.exportToPdf' doesn't always work when called by my node.js app

Tags: pyqgis, node-js

I have a node.js web app that takes some inputs and produces a pdf using the PyQGIS python API. The Python script sometimes fails when calling:

```
exporter.exportToPdf(pdfName, QgsLayoutExporter.PdfExportSettings())
```

When failing, no error messages are returned, but through debugging I've determined that this is the problem line. When the script fails, a pdf file is still created, but it is a corrupt file that doesn't open. I'm not sure what's causing the failure, but the script does 'hang' for a few seconds on this line before failing. The script doesn't fail when the web app is being hosted locally.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see a pattern in the pdfNames that throw errors or other user inputs that may be a factor? Try logging every user input and try to determine a failure pattern.

Comment: All pdfNames are unique and logging is yet to show a pattern to the errors. I've got a temporary fix to the problem now, workspaces are always succesfully created so on fail a second script runs to create the pdf. Not great but it works till logging finds a problem.